# How to add multiple image to canvas using fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, fabricjs

I have read several questions/answers about this topic, but I can't seem to find my solution. So sorry if you guys find this question duplicated.

Here is my situation;
Let's say I have a menu for user to click on it and it will display the image of that selected item on canvas, also user can resize/drag/drop that image as they want. Right now I can make it works only one time with this code

```
addAction(selectedAction: any) {
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  var imgObj = new Image();
  imgObj.src = selectedAction.image;
  imgObj.onload = function() {
    var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgObj, {
        left: 200,
        top: 200,
      });
    canvas.add(imgInstance);
  }
```

The problem is when user click another item in the menu, the previous item that was on the canvas disappear, instead the current item display on the canvas. But if I click on that image, it will disappear and the previous image display on the canvas.

I want them BOTH stay on the canvas at the same time. Please advice.

Comment: You seem to be recreating the canvas every time this function is called.  Try externalizing that and then calling canvas.remove instead to get rid of the previous image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you give me an example code? I'm really new to these canvas stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Real quick answer: http://jsfiddle.net/8yf15nqp/1/.

```
var canvas = ...// setup canvas

function addImage (url) {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function (img) {
        // deal with image
       canvas.add(img);
    });
}
```

Setup a function to handle adding and then call it when you want to add a new image.  I'd assume you'll want to pass the url to the function and do other stuff, but this is a pretty stripped down example.

Comment: This is exactly the solution! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ben Thanks. This works. Why just using `fabric.Image.fromURL` multiple times does not work? More specifically, I use it in a loop and it is always pastes the same image.

Comment: @Simone Do you have a code example?  It's hard to tell what the issue could be without more information.

Comment: Sure. It works when I call your function in a for loop http://jsfiddle.net/ialuronico/wsp91yfc/16/ but if I copy and paste the content of your function in the for loop http://jsfiddle.net/ialuronico/wsp91yfc/15/ it does not work anymore

Comment: The second example is not safe async code.  Both iterations of the loop reference the same `pos` variable in the surrounding scope.  Because the `fabric.Image.fromURL` call is asynchronous, both iterations of the loop execute and then images are loaded into the canvas.  Due to this, both images are loaded onto the canvas with the same `pos` variable.  You can see this in the fiddle by trying to move the image, as the second image is located directly underneath.  I also had to upgrade to fabric 1.7.20 to make the demo work, but that's probably unrelated.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks.